# The text-overflow: ellipsis doesn't work?

Tags: css

```
.one{  background: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.616);
padding: 10px;
width: 610px;
height: 70px;
float: left;
position: relative;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

}

> 

The problem I'm facing is that text-overflow: ellipsis doesn't work here is the code :

And I used the hover the before and the after (i mentioned that because i though it had may had a relation to it)

Comment: Please provide more code in order to demonstrate a minimal, reproducible example.  Make use of the stack snippets to render your markup on screen.

Answer (score 1):

W3Schools is a great reference for CSS. [Its page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) on the `text-overflow` property contains the following statement:

> Both of the following properties are required for text-overflow:
>
> white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;

```css
p {
  margin-top: 3em;
  font-size: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce a finibus felis, eu venenatis velit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Integer quis nunc sodales, fermentum nisi quis, iaculis ipsum. Donec eu mi sit amet neque pretium luctus nec dignissim dolor. Donec ut euismod nibh. Morbi a erat et lacus semper pharetra id dignissim neque. Morbi malesuada sem vitae nunc pellentesque scelerisque. Vivamus vel vehicula nibh. Maecenas efficitur, diam eget malesuada tempor, orci mi interdum purus, sed dictum tortor est nec est. Quisque ex felis, cursus eget est et, viverra dictum tortor. Maecenas laoreet dictum sem, ac rutrum enim vehicula vel. Pellentesque sollicitudin purus in mauris laoreet ultrices. Donec tristique orci eu eleifend iaculis. Sed eget ligula vitae mauris ultrices consectetur in tincidunt erat. Mauris in sollicitudin dui.
</p>
```